# How to create a session array in php

Tags: php

I am just learning php and I just don't understand how to do something that seems should be quite simple.

I have an array with these fields

- date
- income
- county
- state
- count (constant of 1)

I need to create a session array that summarizes the array data 
- county
- state
- income
- count

I just don't know how to create a new Session array to hold the above data.  I have searched and tried but I don't get any closer.  I think I need to have an associative array.

Comment: `if(!session_id()) session_start(); $_SESSION = ['key' => 'value', ...];` - like that etc...

Comment: @sra2786 can you show us your code so far?

Comment: Read about [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Comment: start the session , destroy the session, everything comes between this. $_SESSION is the keyword to create session, rest all is the same like your normal php, creating a variable like this $_SESSION['date'] = "12-12-1999"; accessing the value like this $_SESSION['date'];

Answer (score 0):

I recomend that you take a look at [How to create, Access and Destroy PHP session](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-sessions.php).

As mentioned in the commets above, you may set an your `$_SESSION` superglobal like:

```
// Start the session if it is not already started 
if(!session_id()) {
  session_start(); 
}
// Set the session variables 
$_SESSION = [
  'date'   => 'value1', 
  'income' => 'value2', 
  'county' => 'value2', 
  'state'  => 'value2', 
  'count ' => 1, 
  ...
];
```

You may also set your session like:

```
// Start the session if it is not already started 
if(!session_id()) {
  session_start(); 
}
// Set the session variables 
$_SESSION['date'] = 'value1';
$_SESSION['income'] = 'value2';
$_SESSION['county'] = 'value2';
$_SESSION['state'] = 'value2';
$_SESSION['count '] = 1;
```

Hope this helps,